# Pass a file through different step in PHP

Tags: php, file

I have a scenario like this:

1. page-1 with a form where a select a file (XML) to import
2. after submit, i get redirected to a page-2 where all inputs all pre-compiled by info readed from XML file (the file is uploaded and temporary saved with `tmpfile()` function)
3. if I want to discard or cancel the process to save my data, i can close browser or change page that is ok, cause the file uploaded is a temp file thanks to `tmpfile()` function so it will be deleted automatically by the system....
4. but if I want to confirm the form in page-2 I need to: 1- save all inputs in my database (ok no problem they are all text), 2- move the file selected in step 1 from temp to a directory

The problem is on step 4.2 cause file generated with tmpfile() get deleted after script ends. So I can't move it to a directory.

What's the best way to "propagate" a file from an form-1 to a form-N in PHP ?

I think using file_get_contents() can be a solution using a hidden textarea to pass it on every pages...but for large files i don't know if it's a good idea.

Little pieces of code:

page-2.php

```
 <?php

if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "import" ) {

    if (file_exists($_FILES['fileXMLimport']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileXMLimport']['tmp_name'])) {

    $content = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileXMLimport']['tmp_name']);

    $filename = $_FILES['fileXMLimport']['name'];

}

//omitted: code to read the file xml

//$f1 = "data readed from file";

//

}

?>
 <body>
  <form id="form2">

     <input type="text" name="f1" value="<?php echo $f1; ?>">
     <input type="text" name="f2" value="<?php echo $f2; ?>">
     ...list of field readed from file
     <input type="text" name="fn" value="<?php echo $fn; ?>">

     <textarea class="hidden" name="fileContent"><?php echo base64_encode($content); ?></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="<?php echo $filename; ?>">

     <input type="submit" value="Submit and save file">

  </form>
```

Comment: Have you come across [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Do you realise that PHP places the uploaded file into a temporary file in a specific folder as part of the upload. All you need to do to save it somewhere elese is to do a `move_uploaded_file()` Maybe all you need to do is read [This part of the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) to solve your problem

Comment: Can you show us any code?

Comment: @BudimirSkrtic added a very simple example shrinked from original

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I know I can use another folder to use. In this case in the last form, after confirm, I can unlink() the file to save space. But If I don't confirm the last form and I exit (close browser, change page, ...) I get the file "orphan" saved in that directory and useless... this directory can become very large if this appened frequently.

Comment: You may have to place the file in another folder that You Know is temporary. Then the confirm moves it to a Forever folder. All you then have to do is write a little script to remove files from Your Temp Folder that are older than 60 second or 1 day or whatever criteria you like